# Json Objects Deserializing to Null with PreserveReferencesHandling and Obsolete Properties

Tags: c#, serialization, null, json.net

As my application evolves over time, certain fields and properties that used to be serialized are no longer required.  If you have PreserveReferencesHandling set to either Objects or All and the referenced object was serialized in a property which is no longer required then when the object is deserialized the referenced object would be null.

In this example, I have a Person and a Group class where the Group class contains both Admins and Members:

```
public class Person
{
    public string FullName { get; set; }    
}

public class Group
{
    public List<Person> Admins { get; set; } = new List<Person>();
    public List<Person> Members { get; set; } = new List<Person>();
}
```

Next I create an instance of my group with some admins and members:

```
var chris = new Person { FullName = "Chris" };
var danny = new Person { FullName = "Danny" };
var nick = new Person { FullName = "Nick" };

var group = new Group();
group.Admins.Add(chris);
group.Admins.Add(danny);

group.Members.Add(chris);
group.Members.Add(danny);
group.Members.Add(nick);

var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings { PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects };
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(group, settings);
```

The resulting Json is:

```
{
  "$id": "1",
  "Admins": [
    {
      "$id": "2",
      "FullName": "Chris"
    },
    {
      "$id": "3",
      "FullName": "Danny"
    }
  ],
  "Members": [
    { "$ref": "2" },
    { "$ref": "3" },
    {
      "$id": "4",
      "FullName": "Nick"
    }
  ]
}
```

Over time, we find the Admins property is no longer required and we remove it so the group class becomes:

```
public class Group
{
    public List<Person> Members { get; set; } = new List<Person>();
}
```

The next time that Json is deserialized, the Members collection will contain two nulls and the instance of "Nick".  Is there a way to handle this generically in Json?  I tried creating my own IReferenceResolver but the references in the Admins collection aren't discovered if the Admins property doesn't exist in the class.

I can bring the Admins property back and put the Obsolete attribute on it but I'm hoping there is a generic solution which doesn't require me to keep obsolete fields and properties in my application.